# Python Pandas Dataframe GroupBy Size based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, size

I have a dataframe 'df' that looks like this:

```
id  date1   date2
1   11/1/2016   11/1/2016
1   11/1/2016   11/2/2016
1   11/1/2016   11/1/2016
1   11/1/2016   11/2/2016
1   11/2/2016   11/2/2016
2   11/1/2016   11/1/2016
2   11/1/2016   11/2/2016
2   11/1/2016   11/1/2016
2   11/2/2016   11/2/2016
2   11/2/2016   11/2/2016
```

What I would like to do is to groupby the id, then get the size for each id where date1=date2.  The result should look like:

```
id  samedate    count
1   11/1/2016    2 
1   11/2/2016    1 
2   11/1/2016    2 
2   11/2/2016    2
```

I have tried this:

```
gb=df.groupby(id').apply(lambda x: x[x.date1== x.date2]['date1'].size())
```

And get this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

You could certainly flag each instance where the date1 and date2 are equal, then count those flags for each id by each samedate, but I have to believe there is a groupby option for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first and then aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df.date1 = pd.to_datetime(df.date1)
df.date2 = pd.to_datetime(df.date2)

df = df[df.date1 == df.date2]
gb=df.groupby(['id', 'date1']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (gb)
   id      date1  count
0   1 2016-11-01      2
1   1 2016-11-02      1
2   2 2016-11-01      2
3   2 2016-11-02      2
```

**Timings**:

```
In [79]: %timeit (df[df.date1 == df.date2].groupby(['id', 'date1']).size().reset_index(name='count'))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.84 ms per loop

In [80]: %timeit (df.groupby(['id', 'date1']).apply(lambda x: (x['date1'] == x['date2']).sum()).reset_index())
100 loops, best of 3: 7.57 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
#len df = 10k
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)

df.date1 = pd.to_datetime(df.date1)
df.date2 = pd.to_datetime(df.date2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the 
timings. This is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for answer, first idea was very similar as your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to group on two columns and then apply to check if `date1` equals `date2`

```
In [105]: df.groupby(['id', 'date1']).apply(lambda x: (x['date1'] == x['date2']).sum())
Out[105]:
id  date1
1   11/1/2016    2
    11/2/2016    1
2   11/1/2016    2
    11/2/2016    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: You re going to be slower than jezrael if you apply the lambda function against the entire set and if you do the boolean comparison inside the lambda function.